# Python3 allow for custom key size using AES256

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I am using AES256 in a python project, and the encryption key is entered by the user. I have no way to require the user's key to be a specific length in bytes. I am using the PyCryptodome library for AES256 and when I try to use the keys given for encryption like this:

```
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX)
nonce = cipher.nonce
bal_encrypted, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data.encode("utf8"))
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (26 bytes)
```

I know that AES usually required specific key lengths, but I have seen online tools that allow for AES encryption with custom key size, such as https://encode-decode.com/aes256-encrypt-online/, and I am wondering if there is a way I can implement something similar in Python3.

Comment: You need a *key derivation function* (KDF) - PyCryptodome has several to choose from.

Comment: Usually they pad with zero valued bytes up to the next valid key size (16, 24 or 32) in case you want to copy the **horrid terrible wrong** and **utterly stupid and badly described** but inescapable online F-ing tools. But any cryptographer would indicate that a human entered string is a pass phrase, not a key, and you need a Password Based KDF such as PBKDF2, Argon2 or scrypt to first derive a key (or two) and then use that to encrypt. Describe your protocol. Give it a version number.